# Choose compute node(hypervisor) for instance creation with ansible openstack.cloud.server module

Tags: ansible, openstack, openstack-nova

I am looking to specify which compute node to reside on when creating an instance with Openstack ansible module `openstack.cloud.server`, Actually I want to ansiblealize the following command:

```bash
$ openstack server create --flavor g2 --image Ubuntu-20.04 --network public2 --security-group default --hypervisor-hostname compute3 --os-compute-api-version 2.74 test
# OR
$ openstack server create --flavor g2 --image Ubuntu-20.04 --network public2 --security-group default --host compute3 --os-compute-api-version 2.74 test
```

How I can pass `--host` or `--hypervisor-hostname` similar to Openstack CLI to `openstack.cloud.server` module in ansible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `meta`.`hostname` define you hypervisor:

```
- name: Create a new instance and attaches to a network and passes metadata to the instance
  openstack.cloud.server:
      ......
      meta:
        hostname: test1
```

[meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/server_module.html#parameter-meta):

> A list of key value pairs that should be provided as a metadata to the new instance

Another way, it could use [`availability_zone`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/server_module.html#parameter-availability_zone) parameter to [select hosts](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/admin/availability-zones.html#using-availability-zones-to-select-hosts):

```
- name: launch an instance in specific host
  openstack.cloud.server:
    ......
    availability_zone: nova:compute3001
```

See also this [example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/server_module.html#examples).

Comment: I have also found another solution, setting `openstack.cloud.server: availability_zone: nova:compute3001` will solve the issue, can you add this to your answer too so I can accept it?